# pandas or python equivalent of tidyr complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data that looks like this:

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- tibble(user = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), x = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d"), y = 1)
df

#    user     x     y
# 1     1     a     1
# 2     1     b     1
# 3     2     a     1
# 4     3     a     1
# 5     3     c     1
# 6     3     d     1
```

Python format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'x':['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'd'], 'y':1})
```

I'd like to "complete" the data frame so that every `user` has a record for every possible `x` with the default `y` fill set to 0.

This is somewhat trivial in R (tidyverse/tidyr):

```
df %>% 
    complete(nesting(user), x = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), fill = list(y = 0))

#    user     x     y
# 1     1     a     1
# 2     1     b     1
# 3     1     c     0
# 4     1     d     0
# 5     2     a     1
# 6     2     b     0
# 7     2     c     0
# 8     2     d     0
# 9     3     a     1
# 10    3     b     0
# 11    3     c     1
# 12    3     d     1
```

Is there a `complete` equivalent in pandas / python that will yield the same result?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['user','x'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], df.index.levels[1]],names=['user','x'])
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
    user  x  y
0      1  a  1
1      1  b  1
2      1  c  0
3      1  d  0
4      2  a  1
5      2  b  0
6      2  c  0
7      2  d  0
8      3  a  1
9      3  b  0
10     3  c  1
11     3  d  1
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['user','x'])['y'].unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index(name='y')
print (df)
    user  x  y
0      1  a  1
1      1  b  1
2      1  c  0
3      1  d  0
4      2  a  1
5      2  b  0
6      2  c  0
7      2  d  0
8      3  a  1
9      3  b  0
10     3  c  1
11     3  d  1
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which provides a convenient abstraction to generate the missing rows :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.complete('user', 'x', fill_value = 0)

    user  x  y
0      1  a  1
1      1  b  1
2      1  c  0
3      1  d  0
4      2  a  1
5      2  b  0
6      2  c  0
7      2  d  0
8      3  a  1
9      3  b  0
10     3  c  1
11     3  d  1
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/dev/examples/notebooks/complete.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Another Panda's option could be using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) + [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) + [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt):

```
df2 = (df
       .pivot(index='user', columns='x', values='y')
       .fillna(0)
       .melt(value_name='y', ignore_index=False)
       .reset_index()
       .sort_values(['user', 'x'])
       )
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy now to use those `dplyr`/`tidyr` APIs in python with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, c, tibble, complete, nesting
>>> df = tibble(user=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3), x=c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c", "d"), y=1)
>>> df >> complete(nesting(f.user), x=c("a", "b", "c", "d"), fill={'y': 0})
      user        x         y
   <int64> <object> <float64>
0        1        a       1.0
1        1        b       1.0
2        1        c       0.0
3        1        d       0.0
4        2        a       1.0
5        2        b       0.0
6        2        c       0.0
7        2        d       0.0
8        3        a       1.0
9        3        b       0.0
10       3        c       1.0
11       3        d       1.0
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.