# Expand pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataset of stock data at hand (~10k unique stocks over 60 years). The number of available stock data varies with time. Now, given that I know all unique stocks, I would like to apply some sort of enlargement of my dataframe, like this:

```
given = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
                   "Stock":['Stock 2', 'Stock 1', 'Stock 1', 'Stock 2', 'Stock 3'], 
                   "Return":[0.05, 0.02, 0.01, -0.02, 0]}) 


target = pd.DataFrame({"Date":[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
                   "Stock":['Stock 2', 'Stock 1', 'Stock 3','Stock 1', 'Stock 2', 'Stock 3'], 
                   "Return":[0.05, 0.02, np.nan, 0.01, -0.02, 0]}) 

   Date    Stock  Return
0     1  Stock 2    0.05
1     1  Stock 1    0.02
2     2  Stock 1    0.01
3     2  Stock 2   -0.02
4     2  Stock 3    0.00

   Date    Stock  Return
0     1  Stock 2    0.05
1     1  Stock 1    0.02
2     1  Stock 3     NaN
3     2  Stock 1    0.01
4     2  Stock 2   -0.02
5     2  Stock 3    0.00
```

I.e. even if some stock did not exist at some point in time, i would like to create some form of a placeholder. How can I achieve that in an efficient way? Thanks.

Comment: So in short you want to have NaN's for the stock -returns where there's no value for that day?

Comment: @RobertRedisch exactly. I just added this remark to the description. Thanks.

Comment: Found the link : this should help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44287534/7175713). Dont think it is worth rehashing already solved questions on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate solution using `unstack` and `melt`:

```
target = given.set_index(['Date', 'Stock']).unstack().droplevel(0, 1)
target = target.reset_index().melt('Date', var_name='Stock', value_name='Return').sort_values(by='Date')
```

---

```
# target
   Date    Stock  Return
0     1  Stock 1    0.02
1     1  Stock 2    0.05
2     1  Stock 3     NaN
3     2  Stock 1    0.01
4     2  Stock 2   -0.02
5     2  Stock 3    0.00
```