# add missing values in pandas dataframe - datacleaning

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I have measurements stored in a data frame that looks like the one below.
Those are measurements of PMs. Sensors are measuring the four of them pm1, pm2.5, pm5, pm10 contained in the column indicator, under conditions x1..x56, and it gives the measurement in the column area and count. The problem is that under some condition (columns x1..x56) sensors didn't catch all the PMs. And I want for every combination of column conditions (x1..x56) to have all 4 PM values in column indicator. And if the sensor didn't catch it (if there is no PM value for some combination of Xs) I should add it, and area and count column should be 0.

```
 x1     x2    x3    x4    x5   x6  .. x56    indicator    area    count
 0      0     0     0     0    0   ..  0      pm1           10      56
 0      0     0     0     0    0   ..  0      pm10          9        1
 0      0     0     0     0    0   ..  0      pm5           1       454
     .............................................
 1      0     0     0     0    0   .. 0      pm1            3        4
 ssl    ax    w     45b   g    g  .. gb     pm1            3        4
 1      wdf   sw   d78  b    fd   .. b      pm1            3        4
```

In this example for the first combination of all zeros, pm2.5 is missing so I should add it and put its area and count to be 0. Similar for the second combination (the one that starts with 1). So my dummy example should look like this after I finish:

```
 x1     x2    x3    x4    x5   x6  .. x56    indicator    area    count
 0      0     0     0     0    0   ..  0      pm1           10      56
 0      0     0     0     0    0   ..  0      pm10          9        1
 0      0     0     0     0    0   ..  0      pm5           1       454
 0      0     0     0     0    0   ..  0      pm2.5         0        0
     .............................................
 1      0     0     0     0    0   .. 0      pm1            3        4
 1      0     0     0     0    0   .. 0      pm10           0        0
 1      0     0     0     0    0   .. 0      pm5            0        0
 1      0     0     0     0    0   .. 0      pm2.5          0        0
 ssl    ax    w     45b   g    g  .. gb     pm1             3        4
 ssl    ax    w     45b   g    g  .. gb     pm10            0        0
 ssl    ax    w     45b   g    g  .. gb     pm5             0        0
 ssl    ax    w     45b   g    g  .. gb     pm2.5           0        0

 1      wdf   sw   d78  b    fd   .. b      pm1            3        4
 1      wdf   sw   d78  b    fd   .. b      pm10           0        0
 1      wdf   sw   d78  b    fd   .. b      pm5            0        0
 1      wdf   sw   d78  b    fd   .. b      pm2.5          0        0
```

How I can do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: kindly provide reproducible example. Also, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44287534/7175713) if it helps

Comment: Is the reverse also true? Do you need all combinations of `x`s to exist for each of the `pmxx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to create a MultiIndex from all combinations of `x` and `indicator` then fill missing records.

**Step 1.**
Create a vector of `x` columns:

```
df['x'] = df.filter(regex='^x\d+').apply(tuple, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output:
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x56 indicator  area  count                      x
0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0       pm1    10     56  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
1   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      pm10     9      1  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
2   0   0   0   0   0   0    0       pm5     1    454  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
3   1   0   0   0   0   0    0       pm1     3      4  (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

**Step 2.**
Create the MultiIindex from vector `x` and `indicator` list then reindex your dataframe.

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['x'].unique(),
                                ['pm1', 'pm2.5', 'pm5', 'pm10']],
                                names=['x', 'indicator'])
out = df.set_index(['x', 'indicator']).reindex(mi, fill_value=0)
print(out)

# Output:
                                 x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x56  area  count
x                     indicator                                          
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) pm1         0   0   0   0   0   0    0    10     56
                      pm2.5       0   0   0   0   0   0    0     0      0
                      pm5         0   0   0   0   0   0    0     1    454
                      pm10        0   0   0   0   0   0    0     9      1
(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) pm1         1   0   0   0   0   0    0     3      4
                      pm2.5      *0*  0   0   0   0   0    0     0      0
                      pm5        *0*  0   0   0   0   0    0     0      0
                      pm10       *0*  0   0   0   0   0    0     0      0
#            Need to be fixed ----^
```

**Step 3.**
Group by `x` index to update `x` columns by keeping the highest value for each column of the group (1 > 0).

```
out = out.filter(regex='^x\d+').groupby(level='x') \
         .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(zip(x.columns, x.name)))) \
         .join(out[['area', 'count']]).reset_index()[df.columns[:-1]]
print(out)

# Output:
   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  x56 indicator  area  count
0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0       pm1    10     56
1   0   0   0   0   0   0    0     pm2.5     0      0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0    0       pm5     1    454
3   0   0   0   0   0   0    0      pm10     9      1
4   1   0   0   0   0   0    0       pm1     3      4
5   1   0   0   0   0   0    0     pm2.5     0      0
6   1   0   0   0   0   0    0       pm5     0      0
7   1   0   0   0   0   0    0      pm10     0      0
```

Comment: yes, thanks!!
But how the step 3 would be solved if X columns were strings

Comment: I don't think it changes. I create a tuple of all values of X columns. Have you encountered a problem?

Comment: yeah, i got all zeros for the X columns

Comment: Can you append to your post a such case?

Comment: just did it.. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer and tested on your sample. It seems to work. Can you kindly check it, please?

Comment: It doesn't work.  Area and count are 0 after the step 3 for the records that previously had non-zero values (e.g. for the first 5 rows in your output after the step 3 I got 0 for the area and count).